# abtract is showing me title and university name but cant find the definition

Tags: abstract

i have this command in my latex paper

```
\begin{abstract}
\addchaptertocentry{\abstractname}
```

and somehow the abstract is showing me the title of the paper and the university. But i cant find where this abstract was defined. I would like to change the title but i searched in my main.tex file, couldnt find the definition of the title there.. Where is this located?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Without further information, no one will be able to help you. Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) of what you are doing. Moreover, if the `abstract` definition is nowhere to be found in your document, it is most likely defined in the class you are using.

Comment: yep i found it. Thank you very much